# Запоздавший - запоздалый - припозднившийся, - а предлог?

Tags: предлоги, синонимы, паронимы

> А сверху, по крутой узкой лестнице, ещё продолжали спускаться
>   **запоздавшие с** предыдущего **сеанса** посетители, пока новоприбывшие пребывали в нетерпении.

Это неправленое.

Я, вестимо, нарисую *припозднившихся посетителей,* но можно ли быть припозднившимся с чего-л. (с сеанса)? А если нет, то что можно-то?

---

---

Ой-ё! А *новоприбывшие пребывали* не звучит как аллитерация? нечаемая?

Comment: О чем вы?! Да они не "припозднившиеся С", они с "С сеанса". )))

Answer (score 1):

А сверху, по крутой узкой лестнице, ещё продолжали спускаться **запоздавшие (припозднившиеся)  посетители с предыдущего сеанса**, в то время как **новопришедшие** пребывали в нетерпении.